# How to implement a PHP timeout when waiting for sockets?

Tags: php, sockets, timeout

Ever 60 seconds, I wish to perform some other routine.  During this event, I also wish to take the opportunity to reestablish connection if it drops for whatever reasons.  How can this be accomplished?

```
<?php
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, "123.321.123.321" , 20);
socket_listen ($sock , 10);
while (true) 
{

    //Do some other routine ever 60 seconds

    $client =  socket_accept($sock);  //Blocking function!
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024000);
    $response=processInput($input);
    socket_write($client, $response);
}
```

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793566/php-socket-server-check-if-client-is-alive

Comment: @Revent  Thanks.  It doesn't address the timeout question, but it does addressing recognizing when communication is lost.  Maybe just have two independent programs?  One a 60 second loop (or cron or whatever), and the second similar that I showed?

Comment: Here is a post about that topic, but I'm not sure how useful this will really be to your specific case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310487/start-and-stop-a-timer-php. If I were in your shoes I would look into running the listener as a daemon or something.

Comment: Thanks again Revent,  Yea, doesn't seem like a really good fit.  I know it is off topic, but do you mind pointing me in the right direction how to run a listener as a daemon?  It seems like the way to go, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

use the [stream_select()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.stream-select.php) function.

for example:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8160", $errno,$errorMessage);
$master[] = $socket;
$read = $master;
$write_something = false;
$mod_fd = stream_select($read, $_w, $_e, $write_something ? 0 : 1, 5000);
```